# Calling startActivityForResult never pass to onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I'm calling startActivityForResult from a child activity to MainActivity but never pass for onActivityResult

secondActivty this is the call

```
private void bringMainActivityToTop() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Bundle bun= new Bundle();
    bun.putParcelable("value",new ListData("HelloDummy",longi,lati,"data"));
    intent.putExtra("bundle",bun);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
}
```

And I want see the call in here on the MainActivity I don't care the code I just want to see the call.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    Log.i(TAG,"HelloWorld");

}
```

and the manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.test.mppqvat.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/main_act_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you have to call finish in secondActivity

Comment: thanks all i realized i didnt had clear the how that works now i do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java(in onCreate)

```
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View arg0) {  
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
        }  
    });
```

(outside onCreate)

```
   @Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                        String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                        //use resulted message  
                     }  
 }
```

SecondActivity.java(in onCreate)

```
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                String message=editText1.getText().toString();  
                Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity  
            }  
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult()` belongs to your second activity (if its not then it must to), not the `MainActivity`. `onActivityResult()` method wont trigger in `MainActivity` just cuz `MainActivity` is started for result. Do you realize that?
Also your `MainActivity` if being started for result must SET the result using `setResult()` method and than it has to be finished using `finish()`method, that way the result will be passed from your `MainActivity` to your caller `SeconActivity` activity and its `onActivityResult()` will be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your called Activity must call `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)` or `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)`

Comment: setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); i had this whats the diference?

Comment: when passing a second argument, that argument can contain data that the returning activity wants to pass to the initial caller. Did it work?